# How do I find out what I got "Nice Answer" badge for?

Tags: support, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find out which question/answer awarded you the badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge)

I logged in this morning and there's a "You got a 'Nice Answer' badge" banner on my screen. Cool! But... I can't for the life of me figure out which answer it is for!

The only candidate I plausibly have (e.g. questions that were up-voted within last 2 days and are around 10 and around 20 ranges) is this one with 19 up-votes: [The future of Perl? (Perl 6, Employability)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572704/the-future-of-perl-perl-6-employability/1572732#1572732) - and I don't see any recent down-votes on it so it does not seem like "reached 20 and dropped" situation.

Any way I can figure this out myself? Not terribly critical but I hate unanswered riddles :)

Thanks!

Comment: Nice Answer is for 10 upvotes.

Comment: You have 12 Nice Answer badges and 12 answers >= 10. Couldn't be that hard ;)

Comment: The short answer is: no.  The long answer as well as requests for it, are in the question linked.

Comment: @John - The problem was that NONE of the 12 were up-voted from 9 to 10 within 2 days prior to me seeing the new badge banner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[There is no solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27445/is-it-ok-to-post-there-is-no-solution-answers) to your problem, if posed in general terms.

However, you get that badge at +10. The +20 doesn't come into play at any time. You may have been voted +10, got the badge, and then got 9 more upvotes for a total of +19.

Comment: THanks - i thought 20 gives 2 badges. So much for RTFMing :)