# What should I do, when my question can't get a acceptable answer?

Tags: discussion, questions, unanswered-questions

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083158/how-to-make-the-new-long-shadow-trend-with-css) 5 days ago.
Now I know that there are no solutions for what I was searching for.

So there can't be a correct answer, so I never can mark any answer as the correct one. What should I do now?
Let the question be unanswered or should I write something?

I won't delete the question, because it's a positive upvoted question, so other users are might also interest in a solution or want know that there is no solution.

Comment: You could a note to the question stating that there is no actual solution for the problem.

Comment: Note like an edit in the question? But it's important for me to show everyone that the question is... closed or what ever...

Comment: An answer clearly stating that and most importantly **why** there is no solution to this problem would be a good answer to your question, imo.

Comment: You could answer your own question yourself and add the solution you found or work with.

Comment: @KeesSonnema: I allready post the only possible solution (at this time) in the question. So I should answer it by myself and say, i don't know/found any good solution like nijansen said

Comment: @Bart: not at all, I misread. Retracting. Pity, because I'm sure it is still a dupe of something else here. :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[The fact that there is no solution is a perfectly valid answer to a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27445/is-it-ok-to-post-there-is-no-solution-answers). If that's the conclusion you have reached after extensive research, you should post that as an answer and then accept it (when the system allows you to do so). Or don't: you have no obligation to accept an answer. But either way, there is nothing wrong with answering your own question; in fact, it is encouraged.

These types of answers become *even better* if they explain (1) why the problem is unsolvable, and (2) what alternative or workaround you can (or have chosen to) use instead.

I know you already said you don't want to delete the question, but I'd just like to point out that just because something is unsolvable right now doesn't meant that it always will be. If/when things change, a new answer could be posted with the solution and you could change which one you've accepted. Besides that, you could be wrong about it being an impossible problem. Someone could always come along who knows something you don't. I've been surprised many times in the past.

Comment: `+1` for this great answer. I'm in the same opinion with your last words, maybe there are sometime a new version of a programming language and its going to be possoble with less LoC... I think I wait one more week, then I'll post an answer, that there is no acceptable solution for me AT THIS TIME

Comment: @dTDesign Do allow me to point out here, on an unrelated note, that I think your question is rather unclear. The "edit" you've made is a *major* breaking change compared to the original question; that's a serious problem. But if you're going to edit stuff like that in, don't just throw it in at the bottom without much explanation. What do you mean by transitions? What kinds of transitions? Why do you need fewer lines of code in order to do transitions?

Comment: Good point. I'll edit my question correctly. I'll try to post some examples why I want this... Thank you